# Repeat a background image with Kivy always keeping the image size

Tags: python, kivy

I made a simple example because I can't find a simple answer to this issue, even after looking up Kivy's documentation.
I have the following:
backgroundtest.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Theotherpart(BoxLayout):
    pass

class BgApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Theotherpart()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BgApp().run()
```

and then bg.kv

```
<Theotherpart>
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            source: 'grass.jpg'
```

which, when run, gives the following results:

| Large window | Small window |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Large window] | [image] |

whereas what I would like is this:

| Desired result large | Desired result small |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Desired result large] | [image: Desired result small] |

That is if the image is smaller than the window -> repeat horizontally and vertically.
And if it is bigger than the window -> cut the image.
I tried [this](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/examples/gen__canvas__repeat_texture__py.html) from the Kivy documentation but it still distorts the image when resizing. I also tried to add "keep_ratio: True" in my example but since I'm not declaring an "Image" but a "source" for the rectangle, it doesn't work.

==============================

So I solved the issue by doing the following:

1. Removed the "Theotherpart" class
2. new backgroundtest.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class Texture(Widget):
    texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    tex_size = ListProperty([375,375])
    tex_coords = ListProperty([1,1])
    texture_wrap = StringProperty('repeat')

class BgApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Texture()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BgApp().run()
```

Then in bg.kv

```
<Texture>
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Rectangle:
                size: root.tex_size
                pos: root.tex_coords
                source: 'grass.jpg'
```

Comment: Use a Texture, set its `wrap` property to `"repeat"`, then display it in a Rectangle with tex_coords set to appropriate values.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue. I'm editing my original post with the changes I made so it can help someone else in the future.